# How do you get woothemes shortcodes to work on an archive page of product attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I am not really sure how to ask this question, however if you have a look at this link you will see what I mean

http://www.skirentalwhistler.com/skill-level/beginner

You will see that the shortcodes for a [box] are not being executed.

If you browse a single product, the shortcode works fine - eg click on the first product called  'Compact' and you will see the [box] is executed into the grey box with one grey and one orange button in it.

Also, I have spent a few hours now trying to work out which template is creating this page. The page is a listing of all products with a certain product attribute value (attribute is skill-level and value is beginner)
I expected it to be archive-product.php but it doesn't seem to be, and I can't find any other file dealing with multiple products on a single page

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have worked out how to do it.
Big thanks to chiliNUT for their help, as they helped me to keep going and going.... thus I gave them an uptick

Anyway, it was using the themes archive.php template (not the woocommerce plugin templates as I presumed). In archive.php, I changed the following line in the div class 'entry'

```
<?php if ( $woo_options[ 'woo_post_content' ] == "content" ) the_content(__( 'Read More...', 'woothemes' )); else the_excerpt(); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
```

It now works and doesn't seem to have broken anything else.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using a shortcode in a post, then the `[box]` syntax is what to use. However, if you are doing a shortcode in a template, you must execute the shortcode with php. Since your homepage appears to just display the short code instead of running it, then it is probably in a template. To execute a shortcode in a template, do this

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[box]'); ?>
```

so for the one on your home page

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[box size="small" style="rounded" border="full"]'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I do not know which template is being used on the page in question (not my home page). It is some kind of archive page looping through all products that has a certain value (beginner) for a certain custom product attribute (skill-level).

Comment: just do a search for `[box size="small" style="rounded" border="full"]` in the filesystem

Comment: I do not know what you mean

Comment: You dont know which template it is, so I am assuming that you are not the person who put in that shortcode, but rather, it was the template designer who did? So, if you are in *nix, then on the command line you can do `grep -r "[box size=\"small\" style=\"rounded\" border=\"full\"]" /path/to/wordpress/.` or on a windows box in the command prompt `X:\path\to\wordpress> findstr /s /p [box size=\"small\" style=\"rounded\" border=\"full\"]  *.php` and it will tell you the file that the shortcode is in

Comment: I did put the shortcode in - to the products 'short description'. When displayed on the product page, it executes properly, but for some reason on this 'archive' page the shortcode does not get executed. If I could figure out a way to make sure the do_shortcode() gets fired or if I could figured out which file is the template I should be able to solve the problem.

Comment: ok - finally worked out it is using the themes archive.php template. now to force the shortcodes to work......

Comment: I think its in the way archive.php is displaying the post. If it is displaying it as an excerpt or something other than the full post, that might cause shortcodes to be rendered improperly. Since the shortcode is coming directly from a post, you should not have to wrap it in `do_shortcode`